# Summarize Unique Value

Tags: r, sum, unique, summarize

I have a data set of fantasy football stats that I am using to teach myself R. The data is annual player fantasy football Below is an example of the format it is in.

```
| x | Year| Player    | TM | *Pos*| Age |*FantasyPts*|
| 1 | 2019| *J.Jones*   | ATL| WR | 29  |100       |
| 2 | 2018| *J.Jones*   | ATL| WR | 28  |101.3     |
| 3 | 2019| *A.Rogers*  | GB | QB | 30  |500       |
| 4 | 2017| *A.Peterson*| TM | RB | 29  |12        |

What I want to do is summarize the player data as a whole. So for example summarize the two years together of *J.Jones* to be as follows.

| Player   | *Pos*| *FantasyPts*|
| *J.Jones*  | WR |      201.3|

Any thoughts?
```

Comment: `aggregate(FantasyPts~Player+Pos, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: That did it, thank you!